# Error when insert a data and get it immediately in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm want to insert a new object to mysql and get it to use immediately (in another function). The insert function return ok but when I get it by Id, Get fuction return null. Then I check in db, it inserted. I do get again, now, this object get OK. I don't understand.

*INSERT CODE*

```
public int insert(Object obj) {
    SessionFactory factory = Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(obj);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        factory.close();
        return ErrorCode.OK.code;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        session.close();
        factory.close();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ErrorCode.Not_OK.code;
    }
}
```

*GET CODE*

```
public <T> T get(Class<T> clazz, Serializable id) {
    SessionFactory factory = Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    T t = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        t = (T) session.get(clazz, id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }
    session.close();
            factory.close();
    return t;
}
```

Comment: You should definitly not rebuild the `sessionFactory` every time you perform database access

Comment: How do I check it?